# How to write binary data to a file in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

Iam new to iphone development.

I have binary data(audio file content) in a NSData variable and i want to write that to a file in device.

Can anyone share me a snippet or links of how can i do the same.

Thanks in Advance,
Dinesh

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655558/read-and-write-file-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use :

```
writeToURL:atomically:
writeToFile:atomically:
```